# Renaming files according to a number of chars from the directory name

Tags: files, rename

I have a number of directories like these :

```
./lab-results.n3668.2017-01-16
./lab-results.n471.2017-02-24
./tests.n287.2017-01-28
./tests.n4501.2017-03-04
```

They contain unfortunately **only one file** but the name is the same.

```
./lab-results.n3668.2017-01-16/lab-results.pdf
./lab-results.n471.2017-02-24/lab-results.pdf
./tests.n287.2017-01-28/tests.pdf
./tests.n4501.2017-03-04/tests.pdf
```

I would like to move all these files after having renamed them like this :

```
./lab-results.n3668.pdf
./lab-results.n471.pdf
./tests.n287.pdf
./tests.n4501.pdf
```

So, it seems like some sh scripts I see there but I can't figure out how
I can take a part of the directory's name characters to form the future name of the file.

```
lab-results.n9999 : max number available, will not change
tests.n9999 : max number
```

I also may have others directories but always followed by a bunch of numbers within their names :

```
./xxxxxxx.n9999
./yyyyyy.n9999
./zzz.n9999
```

Any tips or help very much appreciated.
I use bash 4.3.11(1) on a linux distrib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for F in */* ; do echo mv "$F" "${F/.2017*/.pdf}" ; done
```

or as a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
for F in */*
do
    echo mv "$F" "${F/.2017*/.pdf}"
done
```

It just show what to it will do. If it is what you want then remove `echo` and run it.

The trick is with `${F/.2017*/.pdf}`. It searches for `.2017*` in the filename+path and replace it with `.pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I tested both (terminal and sh script). Filenames are unchanged as a result.. I checked each directory, the unique file is still here and its name is not the one issued from its directory.

Comment: @FannyMae you need to remove the `echo` for it to work. Hschou used the `echo` just so you can see what command will be run and make sure it works as expected. If it does, delete the `echo` and run it again and the files will be renamed. Please remember to accept this answer if it does work.

Comment: Hell :-( Sorry for my mistake. I just dont read twice as I should have. It works like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 's|^(\./[^.]*\.[^.]*).*|$1.pdf|' ./*.*.*/*.pdf
```

---

- We select directories that have atleast 2 dots and comprise pdf files.
- Then we keep info until the first 2 dots and construct the new filename.
- This assumes your `rename` is `perl-rename`. Debian-based systems have `perl-rename` as `rename`, others may have it as `perl-rename` or `prename` instead.

Comment: Tested and working. Thanks a lot. Indeed, `man rename` gave me help from Perl Programmers Reference Guide.